# The following text is encoded in base 64. How do I decode it and get the answer?

Tags: base64

```
Ik5ldmVyIHRydXN0IGEgY29tcHV0ZXIgeW91IGNhbid0IHRocm93IG91dCBhIHdpbmRvdyIgLSBTdGV2ZSBXb3puaWFr
```

How do I decode this and get the answer?

Answer (score 5):

Just echo that string into a base64 decoder command, such as `openssl enc -d -base64`.

What you get is:

> "Never trust a computer you can't throw out a window" - Steve Wozniak

Also, you can append that string to a data URI and put that in a browser.

`data:text/plain;base64,Ik5ldmVyIHRydXN0IGEgY29tcHV0ZXIgeW91IGNhbid0IHRocm93IG91dCBhIHdpbmRvdyIgLSBTdGV2ZSBXb3puaWFr`

Comment: Cool trick with the URI thingie.

Answer (score 0):

or

```
echo "Ik5ldmVyIHRydXN0IGEgY29tcHV0ZXIgeW91IGNhbid0IHRocm93IG91dCBhIHdpbmRvdyIgLSBTdGV2ZSBXb3puaWFr" | base64 -d
```